# Fetch inner object array from object array - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a nested object array like below,

```
data = [
  {
    "field": "A",
    "items": [
      {
        "Id": 001,
        "ItemDescription": "item 1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "field": "A",
    "items": [
      {
        "Id": 002,
        "ItemDescription": "item 2"
      },
      {
        "Id": 003,
        "ItemDescription": "item 3"
      },
      {
        "Id": 004,
        "ItemDescription": "item 4"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am trying to fetch only the inner object array from the object array.

I have tried different ways to fetch the inner object array from object array,

```
data.map((u,i) => u[i].map((a,b)=> a.items))
```

expected result:

```
data = [
      {
        "Id": 001,
        "ItemDescription": "item 1"
      },
      {
        "Id": 002,
        "ItemDescription": "item 2"
      },
      {
        "Id": 003,
        "ItemDescription": "item 3"
      },
      {
        "Id": 004,
        "ItemDescription": "item 4"
    
      }
    ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` and `flat`

```js
let data = [
  {
    "field": "A",
    "items": [
      {
        "Id": 001,
        "ItemDescription": "item 1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "field": "A",
    "items": [
      {
        "Id": 002,
        "ItemDescription": "item 2"
      },
      {
        "Id": 003,
        "ItemDescription": "item 3"
      },
      {
        "Id": 004,
        "ItemDescription": "item 4"
      }
    ]
  }
]

let result = data.map(d => d.items).flat();

console.log(result);
```

Output
[image]

Comment: Negative. Not matching my expected result.
above code resulting me below json array.
`[
  [
    {
      "Id": 001,
      "ItemDescription": "eeeee"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Id": 002,
      "ItemDescription": "23434"
    },
    {
      "Id": 003,
      "ItemDescription": "12342"
    },
    {
      "Id": 004,
      "ItemDescription": "type B"
    }
  ]
]`

Comment: It should work. Please check the codepen output in console. https://codepen.io/debraj1983/pen/YzZadRr?editors=0010

Comment: expected result is already mentioned in the question itself. 
I need the items 001 to 004 in a single array object.

Comment: The output is single array which contains 4 objects

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath, why don't you use SO code snippet here to show the OP?

Comment: Can you tell me how to use that? That will be great I guess

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/14032355 , you can just leave your js code in the code snippet

Comment: @ikhvjs This is amazing. Thank you.

Comment: @sisonkk, please run the code snippet in this answer. It returns the result for you.

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath Your answer is correct. But still im not getting my expected result with my array object. I think my problem is something else. I have added my real array screenshot in the question. can you please have a look?

Comment: @sisonkk join this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/233334/raj?tab=general

Answer (score 1):

Just use a single `.map` to get the values in the items `array`

```
let newArr = data.map((u,i) => u.items)
console.log(newArr)
```

and to return all the values in one single array use `.flat`

```
console.log(newArr.flat())
```